# CSS file not found when attempting to overwrite bootstrap with sass?

Tags: html, css, django, sass, bootstrap-4

I have an issue with bootstrap.

I’m attempting to customise my bootstrap theme by using Sass.

I’ve installed it Sass and created two files called main.scss and main.css

In my main.scss file i’ve imported bootstrap via

```
@import "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
```

As seen in the bootstrap documentation on theming

To overwrite the main.css file with the bootstrap package I run

```
sass main.scss main.css
```

I then add main.css as the stylesheet in my html head and delete the bootstrap stylesheet, as everything is now in the main.css file.

When I try to run my program, it keeps telling my it can’t be found.

My html file is located: `/User_testing_v10/user_testing/templates/base.html`
My main.css file is located here: `/User_testing_v10/main.css`

In the html.file i’ve asked it to fetch the main.css file here: `<link rel= "stylesheet" href="/User_testing_v10/main.css”>`

```
Not Found: /User_testing_v10/main.css
[23/Jan/2020 11:02:30] "GET /User_testing_v10/main.css HTTP/1.1" 404 2350
```

What am I doing wrong? Do I need to add static or something?

Thanks for reading this

Answer (score 0):

Change Path like

```
<link rel= "stylesheet" href="../../main.css">
```

Comment: Changed it to: /Users/jakobtolstrup/Desktop/User_testing_v10/user_testing/templates/main.css" 
Get the same error